# TypeScript / React - Trying to Create My Own Button Issue - Function Signature Problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple button in React / TypeScript.

I'm not sure where I am getting the syntax for this incorrect.

Editors don't seem to like the ' => void ' part of my signature.

My goal is to be able to pass down a "clear state" type handler from any parent component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';

// problem is on this line
export function ClearButton(props: {onClick: (React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void}) {
  return (<span
            onClick={(e) => { props.onClick(e) }}>
    <ClearIcon /></span>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot the name of the function's parameter.
**Example:**

```
onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
```

Also, the actual `onClick` on the span should probably be assigned like so:

```
onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}>
```

Alternatively, you could use a shorter syntax in this case, if you prefer.

```
onClick={props.onClick}>
```

So your code becomes:

```
export function ClearButton(props: {onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void}) {
  return (
     <span onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}>
        <ClearIcon />
     </span>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Need more coffee stat!

Comment: Thanks... also going to fix the signature in the question... used wrong type. ChangeEvent instead of MouseEvent

Comment: Ok, then I'll also update the answer to avoid confusing others